# How to get activity reference inside fragment?

Tags: android, dictionary, fragment, onclicklistener, android-fragmentactivity

```
 myOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener(getActivity());
```

I am not getting Activity inside above class. I had Implemented Onclick Event in which i am trying to show Map but I am not getting any Response from on click Method.

```
private static class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final Context context;

        private MyOnClickListener(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String label = "ABC Label";
                String uriBegin = "geo:" + myAdapter.sendLati() + "," + myAdapter.sendLongi();
                String query = myAdapter.sendLati() + "," + myAdapter.sendLongi()  + "(" + label + ")";
                String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
                String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                 startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to set the listener on a View. Just creating it isn't going to do anything.

Comment: how can you start the activity inside static   class

Comment: so what can I do to solve this problem ??

Comment: 1) have you extend your class with Activity?
2) on which (Like Button,Textview..) click you want to do all that process?

Comment: this code inside Fragment and its extend FragmentActivity

Comment: then put whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
private final Activity activity;

private MyOnClickListener(Activity activity) {
     this.activity= activity;
}
```

After Doing this set this listener to your view

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

initiliaze this variable inisde your fargment class.

```
private ActivityName mActivityName;
```

and get it like this inside your fragment function named as "onCreateView"

```
mActivityName = (ActivityName) getActivity();
```

Comment: I hope this helps me.

Answer (score 0):

try with context:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

//set to the view

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(getActivity));
```

Comment: but My OnclickListener Not Working

Comment: have you set this  yourView.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(this));

Comment: above code is working But I have Passed context instead of getActivity